# Changing Date format in Telerik RadDatePicker WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, datepicker

I cannot change the date format in Telerik DatePicker.
I'm trying the below procedure.
I found the following code [here](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.in/2013/09/setting-format-for-telerik-raddatepicker.html)

```cs
public class TelerikDateFormatWorkaround
{
    public CultureInfo CultureWithSwissFormat
    {
        //Hack to get around the fact that there is no custom date format in the Telerik DatePicker
        //http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/datepicker/changing-dateformat.aspx
        get
        {
            var tempCultureInfo = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            tempCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            return tempCultureInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadDatePicker">
        <Setter Property="Culture" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource TelerikDateFormatWorkaround}, Path=CultureWithSwissFormat}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

But I have the following error `The TelerikDateFormatWorkaround was not found.`

Can you help me?

Comment: Note the comment in the sample you linked states "Add it to the usercontrol resources".  Where are you doing this?  What does the code segment look like?

Comment: In the `TargetType="telerik:RadDatePicker"`

Answer (score 2):

You should create instance of `TelerikDateFormatWorkaround` in xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>       
    <local:TelerikDateFormatWorkaround x:Key="TelerikDateFormatWorkaround" />

    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadDatePicker">
        <Setter Property="Culture" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource TelerikDateFormatWorkaround}, Path=CultureWithSwissFormat}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

`local` is namespace where you defined `TelerikDateFormatWorkaround` class:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TelerikWorkaround"
```